# Cómo sumar dos campos en consulta con Maria DB

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

¿Cómo puedo sumar dos o más campos en maria db?

Lo he intentado con sum y con +, pero no funciona.

```
SELECT id_tr, numero_linea enero_tr, febrero_tr, marzo_tr, abril_tr, mayo_tr, junio_tr, julio_tr, agosto_tr, septiembre_tr, octubre_tr, noviembre_tr, diciembre_tr, SUM('enero_tr','febrero_tr','marzo_tr','abril_tr','mayo_tr','junio_tr','julio_tr','agosto_tr','septiembre_tr','octubre_tr','noviembre_tr','diciembre_tr'), meta2_tr, meta1_tr
```

Answer (score 1):

Ponlo sin las comillas y separando los SUM...

```
SELECT id_tr, numero_linea enero_tr, febrero_tr, marzo_tr, abril_tr, mayo_tr, junio_tr, julio_tr, agosto_tr, septiembre_tr, octubre_tr, noviembre_tr, diciembre_tr, SUM(enero_tr) + SUM(febrero_tr) + SUM(marzo_tr) + SUM(abril_tr) + SUM(mayo_tr) + SUM(junio_tr) + SUM(julio_tr) + SUM(agosto_tr) + SUM(septiembre_tr) + SUM(octubre_tr) + SUM(noviembre_tr) + SUM(diciembre_tr), meta2_tr, meta1_tr
```

Answer (score 1):

SUM() no es la función indicada para hacer la suma de campos, o al menos no en este caso, teniendo en cuenta que es una función de agregación.

La adición de dos o más campos se puede realizar usando el operador de adición, o sea: `+`

```
SELECT id_tr, numero_linea enero_tr, febrero_tr, marzo_tr, abril_tr, mayo_tr, junio_tr, 
julio_tr, agosto_tr, septiembre_tr, octubre_tr, noviembre_tr, diciembre_tr, 
(enero_tr + febrero_tr + marzo_tr + abril_tr + mayo_tr + junio_tr + julio_tr + agosto_tr
+ septiembre_tr + octubre_tr + noviembre_tr + diciembre_tr) AS sumaMeses, 
meta2_tr, meta1
```